# How do programming Python & Django in visual studio 2010?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010

I work Python and django with linux(ubuntu) also I work C# with visual studio 2010
but I want to work Python & django with visual studio 2010, i do first steps for programming in this but cannot run projects in browser like linux.
please help me about this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get your question... But to get python to work in visual studio you need to be able to compile it.

If you want an easy fix use pytools:
http://pytools.codeplex.com/

If you want to do it yourself Read up on python compiling for VS here:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/VS2010